# file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, composer-php, mamp

I have to run a Laravel project locally in MAMP to do some tests. I cloned from the Github repository and I created a new branch. Then, I followed the instructions from [this](https://gist.github.com/hootlex/da59b91c628a6688ceb1) tutorial:

- Rename .`env.example` file to `.env` inside your project root and fill the
  database information. (windows wont let you do it, so you have to
  open your console cd your project root directory and run `mv
  .env.example .env`)
- Open the console and `cd` your project root directory
- Run `composer install` or `php composer.phar install`
- Run `php artisan key:generate`
- Run `php artisan migrate`
- Run `php artisan db:seed` to run seeders, if any.
- Run `php artisan serve`

However, when I try to access the url written in the response message of the `php artisan serve` command, I get the following error message:

```
file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed (View home.blade.php)
```

How can I fix this kind of error? Is it a MAMP configuration problem or a project related issue?

Comment: "certificate verify failed" the certificate given by the server is probably coming from a CA that the client does not know about (or intermediate certificate are not sent properly by the server, or there are other invalid properties in the certificate, like begin/end date, but in all cases one has to see the certificate to know that...)

Comment: I'm testing outside MAMP environment and I get the same error? Most likely, there is something wrong in my SSL configuration. How do I fix it? Or, is there a workaround?